# Refresh and load one particular fragment of the previous activity

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I have 3 fragments in a activity. One of the fragment displays the list of items along with price and quantity. On selecting any of the item , a new activity will start that will display the details of the item. In this activity we can change the item price , quantity etc.
I want to reload and display the fragment(with updated values) in previous activity just after saving the changes in the item detail activity.

Here is the code for first activity:

```
 public class SupplierHomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  
 ActionBar.TabListener {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_supplier_home);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
       // getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(getListener());
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new Fragment(), "PROFILE");
        adapter.addFragment(new InventoryFragment(), "INVENTORY");
        adapter.addFragment(new SupplierOrderFragment(), "ORDERS");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your adapter globally and add **onResume()** method to notify your adapter that data has been changed for the content.